# How do you position a table body to "fit" into table headers and row headers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table like so:
[image]
I am wondering how to have the table body fit between these headers for both the columns and rows. 
Currently, when inserting a new row and table data into the table body it is inserted under the total.

I would like that when inserting new rows/data using javascript, it will be inserted in the space left by the column and row headers. In the "gap".

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Times, serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html{
  background-color: #35454E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html *{
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: white !important;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
table, th, td{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MMS.css">
  <title>Money Management</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mainTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>2019</th>
        <th colspan="5">January</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Weeks</th>
        <th>31/12/2018</th>
        <th>07/01/2019</th>
        <th>14/01/2019</th>
        <th>21/01/2019</th>
        <th>28/01/2019</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pay</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rent</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="MMS.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
'use strict'
let table = document.getElementById("mainTable")
let cell1 = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(0).insertCell(0)
cell1.innerHTML = "hello world"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmrb4p5x/1/

Comment: you should read a basic tutorial on how to build a table . th can be used to name a column and also a row, when it stands in a row, it belongs to it , and therefor , if its in tbody content, tht's where they are meant to be : https://jsfiddle.net/ark8fc4m/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics

Comment: I understand you can do that but that makes future features more difficult to implement, I was wondering if you can fit a tbody inside of the space created by the headers.

Comment: I'd argue that the results of criticism (especially friendly criticism) are solely based on the person *receiving* the criticism. All of this aside, I've fixed your question, but am still not clear. When you say "Add rows", are you referring to the HTML or JavaScript? Can you describe the "new data" you're adding to the table and how you're doing so? To fill this table you should be adding `<td>` elements to the rows that are already there, not adding more rows.

Comment: if it doesn't work the way you want, then you do not need a table ?

Comment: @TylerRoper Ive updated the question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Can you share your javascript? Your code should loop through each existing row in `<tbody>`, adding 5 `<td>` elements for each, rather than adding new rows.

Comment: Ive added the js to the question , did try to add it to the snippets but couldnt get it work for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding rows, consider moving your data rows to `<tbody>`, looping through them, and adding a cell for each column like so:

```js
let table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
rows.forEach(row => {
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "5"; //28/01/2019
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "4"; //21/01/2019
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "3"; //14/01/2019
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "2"; //07/01/2019
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "1"; //31/12/2018
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Times, serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #35454E;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html * {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: white !important;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MMS.css">
  <title>Money Management</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="mainTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>2019</th>
        <th colspan="5">January</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Weeks</th>
        <th>31/12/2018</th>
        <th>07/01/2019</th>
        <th>14/01/2019</th>
        <th>21/01/2019</th>
        <th>28/01/2019</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Balance</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pay</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rent</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="MMS.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a pretty clean solution. I was hoping to have the data completely separate from the headers but is this not at all possible with tables? Other than having multiple tables just to hold the headers or something like that?

Comment: You could either make your own table using `<div>` and whatnot, or you could nest a table within a table (but then you run into alignment issues). I think this may be your best bet. Depending on what your data looks like, the "proper" way would likely be to build the table *from* the data. I.e. add a row for each property.

Comment: Yeh I wouldn't even bother trying the div approach and I gave the nesting tables approach a go but like you say the alignment just was all over the place. Okay, I'm sure I can work around it for future features, was just hoping to not have to account for headers when doing operations on the data. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just include the `<th>` header cell in the `<tbody>` rows as the first cell. `<th>` isn't limited to just `<thead>` nodes.

```
      <tr>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
```

Like this:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Times, serif;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html{
  background-color: #35454E;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html *{
  font-family: "Work Sans", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: white !important;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
table, th, td{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MMS.css">
  <title>Money Management</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mainTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>2019</th>
        <th colspan="5">January</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Weeks</th>
        <th>31/12/2018</th>
        <th>07/01/2019</th>
        <th>14/01/2019</th>
        <th>21/01/2019</th>
        <th>28/01/2019</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pay</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rent</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="MMS.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). My only concern with this approach is it makes some future features harder to implement. I am trying to keep the headers completely separate from the body if possible

Comment: hmmm that does make it more of a challenge

Comment: Yeh, i realize tables probably aren't designed for that purpose but it seems to be the best tool currently

Comment: @Dean Well here is a possible solution with just CSS, though it might not be that flexible ... [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bf0Lmcg/)